# How to send an EMAIL using c++ and SMTP in Visual studio. Without including .exe files

Tags: c++, smtp, google-developers-console

I got stuck in **sending an email using c++**, without any external sources, only standard libraries are included. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmm...a quick check of the C++ standard, mentions 'email' only related to the contact email for the standardization committee....apart from that there is zilch in it. So then the answer to your question would be .....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Can be done if you use bare-bones SMTP and whatever TCP stack API is offered by your target operating system, but will be rejected by practically every e-mail server due to the utter lack of security. Bite the bullet and use a third party library.